# how to validate data on text?

Tags: php, html

I have this project where in it requires to validate the data on text field if the user input "0" the process must not run and display an error message instead.. here's my code:

```
<?php
include('connect.php');
include('func.php');
if (isset($_REQUEST['command'])=='delete' && $_REQUEST['pid']>0){
    remove_product($_REQUEST['pid']);
}
else if (isset($_REQUEST['command'])=='update') {
    $max=count($_SESSION['cart']);
    for($i = 0;$i < $max; $i++) {
        $pid = $_SESSION['cart'][$i]['productid'];
        $q = intval($_REQUEST['product'.$pid]);
        if( $q > 0 && $q <= 999){
            $_SESSION['cart'][$i]['qty']=$q;
        }
        else{
             echo "Some products not updated!, quantity must be a number between 1 and 999";
        }
    }
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN""http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<script language="javascript">
function del(pid){
    if(confirm('Do you really mean to delete this item')){
        document.form1.pid.value=pid;
        document.form1.command.value='delete';
        document.form1.submit();
    }
}
function clear_cart(){
    if(confirm('This will empty your shopping cart, continue?')){
        document.form1.command.value='clear';
        document.form1.submit();
    }
}
function update_cart(){
    document.form1.command.value='update';
    document.form1.submit();
}
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="lib/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#qty").keypress(function (e) {
        if( e.which!=8 && e.which!=0 && (e.which<48 || e.which>57))
        {
            return false;
        }
    });
});
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="lib/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="src/facebox.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('a[rel*=facebox]').facebox({
        loadingImage : 'src/loading.gif',
        closeImage   : 'src/closelabel.png'
    })
})
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
function checkCheckBox(){
    agree_check = oForm.elements["agree"].checked;
    if(!agree_check){
        alert("You must agree to the terms and conditions before purchasing.");
    }
    return agree_check;
}
</script>

<style type="text/css">
body {
    background-color: #FFF;
}
table {
    margin-top: 15px;
}
#wrapper {
    width:900px;
    height:auto;
    margin-left:40px;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div id="wrapper">
    <table width="900" align="center">
    <tr>
        <td><img src="images/banner.png" width="900" height="138" /></td>
    </tr>



<form name="form1">
    <input type="hidden" name="pid" />
    <input type="hidden" name="command" />
    <div style="margin:0px auto; width:600px;" >
    <div style="padding-bottom:10px">
        <h1 align="center">Your Shopping Cart</h1>
        <input type="button" value="Continue Shopping" <onclick="window.location='customerproduct.php'" />
    </div>
    <table border="0" cellpadding="5px" cellspacing="1px" style="font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; font-size:11px; background-color:#E1E1E1" width="100%">
    <?php
    if(isset($_SESSION['cart'])){
        echo '<tr bgcolor="#FFFFFF" style="font-weight:bold"><td>Serial</td><td>Name</td><td>Price</td><td>Qty</td><td>Amount</td><td>Options</td></tr>';
        $max = count($_SESSION['cart']);
        for($i = 0; $i < $max; $i++){
            $pid = $_SESSION['cart'][$i]['productid'];
            $q = $_SESSION['cart'][$i]['qty'];
            $pname = get_product_name($pid);
            if ($q == 0) continue;
    ?>
        <tr bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><td><?php echo $i+1?></td><td><?php echo $pname?></td>
        <td><?php echo number_format(get_price($pid))?>Php</td>
        <td><input type="text" id="qty" name="product<?php echo $pid?>" value="<?php echo $q?>" maxlength="3" size="2" /></td>                    
        <td><?php echo number_format(get_price($pid)*$q)?>Php</td>
        <td><a href="javascript:del(<?php echo $pid?>)">Remove</a></td></tr>
        <?php } ?>
        <tr>
            <td><b>Order Total: <?php echo number_format(get_order_total())?>Php</b></td>
            <td colspan="5" align="right">
                <input type="button" value="Update Cart" onclick="update_cart()">
                <input type="checkbox" value="0" name="agree">
                <a rel="facebox" href="terms.php"?>terms and condition</a>
                <input type="button" id="place" value="Place Order" onclick="window.location='order.php'" >
            </form></td>
        </tr>
    <?php } ?>
    </table>
    </div>
</form>
```

I like to display the error message when the user inputs "0" in the text of `quantity`.

Comment: Isn't that what `if($q>0 && $q<=999){` does?

Comment: Not sure if it's your issue, but there's a few issues with your code. 1) You include `lib/jquery.js` twice - only need it once. 2) The input after "Your Shopping Cart" has a `<` before the `onclick` attribute - it shouldn't. 3) You have an extra `</form>` tag at the bottom. 4) I generally recommend closing `input` elements, although it isn't necessary in HTML 5 (`<input name=".." type=".." />`). 5) It'll be a lot easier to manage if you separate all the pieces - CSS & JS should be external, do all PHP at the top (except output, obviously)

Answer (score 0):

use **javascript** to validate it this way :

```
document.getElementById("qty").onkeyup=function(){

   if(this.value == "0")
    {
      this.value = "";
      alert("Wrong quantity entered. Please enter again");
    }

};
```

you may also use the `onchange` instead of `onkeyup` event :

```
document.getElementById("qty").onchange=function(){

   if(this.value == "0")
    {
      this.value = "";
      alert("Wrong quantity entered. Please enter again");
    }

};
```

Comment: its not working.. when i tried to input 0 value and when i click <input type="button" id="place" value="Place Order" onclick="window.location='order.php'" > button nothing happens.. :(

Comment: where did  you place this javascript @BonCorcino ???
you need to place this just before the closing `</body>` tag

Answer (score 0):

Replace your

```
echo "Some products not updated!, quantity must be a number between 1 and 999";
```

with

```
echo "<script>alert('Some products not updated!, quantity must be a number between 1 and 999')";
exit;
```

Answer (score 0):

I can see that you've been using JavaScript to prompt user when they clear the cart, you can use Javascript to warn user again if they give the qty value of '0';

```
 <input type="text" id="qty" onblur="if(this.value==0){alert('Please enter a quantity ! ');}"   name="product<?php echo $pid?>" value="<?php echo $q?>" maxlength="3" size="2" />
```

I can also see you've try to validate the request in PHP. Instead of echoing the error out you can store it into a variable:

```
    $err = '';
 if($q>0 && $q<=999){
        $_SESSION['cart'][$i]['qty']=$q;

    }
    else{
         $err = "Some products not updated!, quantity must be a number between 1 and 999";
    }
```

And then you pick a place to display the message in the HTML

```
<td><input type="text" id="qty" name="product<?php echo $pid?>" value="<?php echo $q?>" maxlength="3" size="2" /><?php echo $err; ?></td>
```

Comment: it just show error undefined variable err on this line <input type="text" id="qty" onblur="if(this.value==0){alert('Please enter a quantity ! ');}" name="product<?php echo $pid?>" value="<?php echo $q?>" maxlength="3" size="2" /><?php echo $err; ?> .. :(

Comment: ok, need to move the $err ='' to the top of the page within the php block.